# BLE scan only gets the name of some devices on the first scan

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I have the following code:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEAdvertisedDevice.h>

static void log(String message) {
  Serial.println(message);
}

const char* deviceName = "BLEScanner";
BLEScan* pBLEScan;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);   
  log("Setup!");
  BLEDevice::init(deviceName);
  pBLEScan = BLEDevice::getScan(); //create new scan
  pBLEScan->setActiveScan(true); //active scan uses more power, but get results faster
  pBLEScan->setInterval(100);
  pBLEScan->setWindow(99); // less or equal setInterval value    
}

void loop() {
  log("Listing BLE Sensors");
  BLEScanResults foundSensors = pBLEScan->start(30, false);
  int count = foundSensors.getCount();
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    BLEAdvertisedDevice bleSensor = foundSensors.getDevice(i);
    String sensorName = bleSensor.getName().c_str();
    String address = bleSensor.getAddress().toString().c_str();
    log(address + " " + sensorName);
  }
  log("Sleeping");
  sleep(10);
}
```

And when running it I get the following output:

```
Setup!
Listing BLE Sensors
00:09:b0:09:e7:ca 
41:59:8f:07:ec:96
ac:5d:5c:e1:72:89 LM0845
c4:7c:8d:6a:36:cf Flower care
c4:7c:8d:6a:45:6b Flower care
c4:7c:8d:6a:46:2c Flower care
de:d5:2a:8e:1e:fd Tile
Sleeping
Listing BLE Sensors
00:09:b0:09:e7:ca 
41:59:8f:07:ec:96
ac:5d:5c:e1:72:89
dc4:7c:8d:6a:36:cf
dc4:7c:8d:6a:45:6b
dc4:7c:8d:6a:46:2c
de:d5:2a:8e:1e:fd Tile
Sleeping
Listing BLE Sensors
00:09:b0:09:e7:ca 
41:59:8f:07:ec:96
ac:5d:5c:e1:72:89
c4:7c:8d:6a:36:cf
dc4:7c:8d:6a:45:6b
dc4:7c:8d:6a:46:2c
de:d5:2a:8e:1e:fd Tile
... and so on
```

For some reason I only get the names of some of the devices the first time, is this a known error and what can be done about it?

I have tried to put a `pBLEScan->clearResults();` before I start a scan but that did not help.

I'm using an ESP32 Adafruit feather.

The only solution I have found is to put the `BLEDevice::init(deviceName);` inside the loop and then run `BLEDevice::deinit();` before sleep!